# Generating time dropdowns with empty values in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Inside a form in one of the view files, I generate a dropdown for specifying time like following:

```
echo $this->Form->input('start_time', array('label'=>false, 'timeFormat' => '24', 'interval'=> '10', 'selected' => '00:00','type'=>'time'));
```

it generates two dropdowns: one for hours and one for minutes. The preselected value is as stated 00:00. If no value is chosen, the dropdown shows current time.

What I want it to do instead, is to produce empty values, so the dropdown for hours would be like: " , 00, 01, 02..."

Comment: I would just create my own select inputs for hours and minutes that have the options you want.

Comment: And don't use `selected`, that's wrong. Use `default` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just pass through `'empty' => ''` as an extra param. And then, pass '' as the default value. Don't pass 'selected' at all.

Your code will look like this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('start_time', array('label'=>false, 'timeFormat' => '24', 'interval'=> '10', 'default' => '','type'=>'time', 'empty' => ''));
```

See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#options-for-select-checkbox-and-radio-inputs